# QBS: Explicitly setting qbs.profiles inside Products causing build to fail

Tags: qt, qbs

My use-case is this:

I have a static library which I want to be available for some profiles (e.g. "gcc", "arm-gcc", "mips-gcc").

I also have an application which links to this library, but this applications should only build using a specific profile (e.g. "arm-gcc").

For this I am modifying the app-and-lib QBS example.

The lib.qbs file:

```
import qbs 1.0

Product {
    qbs.profiles: ["gcc", "arm-gcc", "mips-gcc"] //I added only this line
    type: "staticlibrary"
    name: "mylib"
    files: [
        "lib.cpp",
        "lib.h",
    ]
    Depends { name: 'cpp' }
    cpp.defines: ['CRUCIAL_DEFINE']

    Export {
        Depends { name: "cpp" }
        cpp.includePaths: [product.sourceDirectory]
    }
}
```

The app.qbs file:

```
import qbs 1.0

Product {
    qbs.profiles: ["arm-gcc"] //I added only this line
    type: "application"
    consoleApplication: true
    files : [ "main.cpp" ]
    Depends { name: "cpp" }
    Depends { name: "mylib" }
}
```

The app build fails. Qbs wrongly tries to link to the "gcc" version of the library instead of the "arm-gcc" version, as you can see in the log:

```
Build graph does not yet exist for configuration 'default'. Starting from scratch.
Resolving project for configuration default
Setting up build graph for configuration default
Building for configuration default
compiling lib.cpp [mylib {"profile":"gcc"}]
compiling lib.cpp [mylib {"profile":"arm-gcc"}]
compiling lib.cpp [mylib {"profile":"mips-gcc"}]
compiling main.cpp [app]
creating libmylib.a [mylib {"profile":"gcc"}]
creating libmylib.a [mylib {"profile":"mips-gcc"}]
creating libmylib.a [mylib {"profile":"arm-gcc"}]
linking app [app]
ERROR: /usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ -o /home/user/programs/qbs/usr/local/share/qbs/examples/app-and-lib/default/app.7d104347/app /home/user/programs/qbs/usr/local/share/qbs/examples/app-and-lib/default/app.7d104347/3a52ce780950d4d9/main.cpp.o /home/user/programs/qbs/usr/local/share/qbs/examples/app-and-lib/default/mylib.eyJwcm9maWxlIjoiZ2NjIn0-.792f47ec/libmylib.a

ERROR: /home/user/programs/qbs/usr/local/share/qbs/examples/app-and-lib/default/mylib.eyJwcm9maWxlIjoiZ2NjIn0-.792f47ec/libmylib.a: error adding symbols: File format not recognized
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
ERROR: Process failed with exit code 1.
The following products could not be built for configuration default:
app
```

The build fails only when selecting **one** profile in the app.qbs file, and this profile should not be the first profile in the qbs.profiles line in the lib.qbs file.

When selecting two or more profiles - the build succeeds.

### My analysis:

I think this problem is related to multiplexing:

The lib.qbs contains more than one profile. This turns on multiplexing when building the library, which, in turn, adds additional '`multiplexConfigurationId`' to the build-directory name (`moduleloader.cpp`).

The app.lib contains only one profile, so multiplexing is not turned on and the build-directory name does not get the extra string.

The problem can be solved by changing the code (`moduleloader.cpp`) so that multiplexing is turned even if there is only one profile i.e. with the following patch:

```
--- moduleloader.cpp    2018-10-24 16:17:43.633527397 +0300
+++ moduleloader.cpp.new    2018-10-24 16:18:27.541370544 +0300
@@ -872,7 +872,7 @@
             = callWithTemporaryBaseModule<const MultiplexInfo>(dummyContext,
                                                                extractMultiplexInfoFromProduct);

-    if (multiplexInfo.table.size() > 1)
+    if (multiplexInfo.table.size() > 0)
         productItem->setProperty(StringConstants::multiplexedProperty(), VariantValue::trueValue());

     VariantValuePtr productNameValue = VariantValue::create(productName);
@@ -891,7 +891,7 @@
         const QString multiplexConfigurationId = multiplexInfo.toIdString(row);
         const VariantValuePtr multiplexConfigurationIdValue
             = VariantValue::create(multiplexConfigurationId);
-        if (multiplexInfo.table.size() > 1 || aggregator) {
+        if (multiplexInfo.table.size() > 0 || aggregator) {
             multiplexConfigurationIdValues.push_back(multiplexConfigurationIdValue);
             item->setProperty(StringConstants::multiplexConfigurationIdProperty(),
                               multiplexConfigurationIdValue);
```

This worked for my use case. I don't know if it make sense in a broader view.

### Finally, the questions:

Does it all make sense?

Is this a normal behavior?

Is this use-case simply not supported?

Is there a better solution?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the default behavior with multiplexing is that the a non-multiplexed product depends on all variants of the dependency. In general, there is no way for a user to change that behavior, but there should be.
However, luckily for you, profiles are special:

```
Depends { name: "mylib"; profiles: "arm-gcc" }
```

This should fix your problem.

Comment: Thank you @Christian, but your suggestion works only when selecting one profile. If, in app.qbs I use 

`qbs.profiles: ["gcc", "arm-gcc"]`

and  
`Depends { name: "mylib"; profiles: ["gcc", "arm-gcc"] }`

I still get the link errors.

Comment: Sure, because now both your app variants depend on both lib variants, which is wrong. In this case, the default behavior does the right thing, so you could just use a plain Depends item. Now that I think about it, this one should work for both cases: Depends { name: "mylib"; profiles: qbs.profile }